# Determine application executing directory on server or client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, system.reflection

Here is my problem. I want to load libraries into my application at runtime. This will allow the application to consume new implementations of an interface without needing re-compilation.  The application will search its own directory for the libraries. I have code that achieves this:

```
 var path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
 path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
 path = Path.Combine(path, "<my assembly>.dll");

 var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
```

This code works perfectly in a unit test. However, the application is a web application. When I run this code as part of the application, `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` returns a temporary directory within the .net framework. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\...) I could probably fix this by using `Server.MapPath`, but then the code won't be unit testable anymore.

I'd really like to find something that will give me the executing directory in a platform-agnostic manner, that is, it searches the correct directory in both a unit test and a web application.

I've tried:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location //Works as a test but not on a server
Application.ExecutablePath //Not an executable, so this won't work
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory //Almost works in web app, but stops too early in the directory structure
Environment.CurrentDirectory //returns system32 directory
```

Comment: GetCallingAssembly also returns a directory within the .net framework when run as a web app.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've used that works both under test environment and the web application:

```
    private static string AssemblyDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            var uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Luke how is that different to the answer provided by Sergey Litvinov ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use such method. It will return real location of assembly.

```
public static string GetAssemblyLocation(Assembly assembly)
{
    if (assembly.IsDynamic)
    {
        return null;
    }

    string codeBase = assembly.CodeBase;
    UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);

    string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
    path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    path += "\\" + Path.GetFileName(assembly.Location);

    return path;
}
```

[CodeBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.reflection.assembly.codebase%28v=vs.100%29) will return original location of the assembly. In case of web application, when all assemblies use shadow copy in Temporary folder, CodeBase still will return path in Bin folder. But with protocol, like this file://c:/somesite/bin/someassembly.dll. So this method just get it and converts it to usual file path.